# How to set browser's width and height in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, height, width, window-size

I'm using Selenium WebDriver for Python.
I want instantiate the browser with a specific width and height. So far the closest I can get is:

```py
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_window_size(1080,800)
```

Which works, but sets the browser size after it is created, and I want it set at instantiation. I'm guessing there is an approach along the lines of:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile();
profile.set_preference(foo, 1080)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

But I don't know what `foo` would be, and I can't figure out where the docs are.

**Q1:** is there a way to set width / height at instantiation?

**Q2:** Where are the reference docs listing all keys usable by `profile.set_preference`?

Comment: Why is it a bad thing that it resizes after being created?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. Strictly speaking it's different to a window being opened at a specific size (I can **see** the difference). I don't know whether that difference is _material_. Seeing as these are tests, I'd like to remove as many unknowns as possible. If someone can tell me that it makes no difference then I'd be happy. But they'd probably need to know the specifics of my test to do that, and I want to be able to do this for all future tests that I write.

Comment: I would agree with Arran.  I can't think of any reason why resize after creation would cause issues.

Answer (score 68):

Here's a solution that works with both headless and non-headless mode and will start the window with the specified size instead of setting it after:

#### Chrome:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions

opts = ChromeOptions()
opts.add_argument("--window-size=2560,1440")

driver = Chrome(options=opts)
```

#### Firefox:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox, FirefoxOptions

opts = FirefoxOptions()
opts.add_argument("--width=2560")
opts.add_argument("--height=1440")

driver = Firefox(options=opts)
```

Comment: The equivalent in Chrome is "--window-size=2560,1440".

Comment: THIS is the right answer here, thanks

Answer (score 55):

Here is how I do it in Python with Selenium 2.48.0:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
driver = Firefox()
driver.set_window_position(0, 0)
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
```

Comment: The OP explicitly says they don't want to set it after creation. The code in the question already shows them using `set_window_size`.

Comment: `set_window_position(0,0)` positions the window about 10 pixels off the left of screen annoyingly.

Answer (score 46):

For me, the only thing that worked in Java 7 on OS X 10.9 was this:

```java
// driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(grid), capability);
driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(0,0));
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1024,768));
```

Where `1024` is the width, and `768` is the height.

Answer (score 19):

Try something like this:

```
IWebDriver _driver = new FirefoxDriver();
_driver.Manage().Window.Position = new Point(0, 0);
_driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(1024, 768);
```

Not sure if it'll resize after being launched though, so maybe it's not what you want

Comment: Isn't it suppose to be python

Answer (score 13):

If you are using chrome

```
 chrome_options = Options()
 chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized");
 chrome_options.add_argument("--window-position=1367,0");
 if mobile_emulation :
     chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)

  self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver', 
                                  chrome_options = chrome_options)
```

This will result in the browser starting up on the second monitor without any annoying flicker or movements across the screen.

Comment: Do you know how to do the same trick in Firefox? Maybe you can answer [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54575853/8973620).

Answer (score 4):

It's easy. Here is the full code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("Your URL")
driver.set_window_size(480, 320)
```

> Make sure chrome driver is in your system path.

Comment: the question requires you to set the size before instantiating the driver

Comment: This works for me

Comment: This only happens after the window is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Here is firefox profile default prefs from python selenium 2.31.0 firefox_profile.py

and type "about:config" in firefox address bar to see all prefs

reference to the entries in about:config: http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries

```
DEFAULT_PREFERENCES = {
    "app.update.auto": "false",
    "app.update.enabled": "false",
    "browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting": "false",
    "browser.EULA.override": "true",
    "browser.EULA.3.accepted": "true",
    "browser.link.open_external": "2",
    "browser.link.open_newwindow": "2",
    "browser.offline": "false",
    "browser.safebrowsing.enabled": "false",
    "browser.search.update": "false",
    "extensions.blocklist.enabled": "false",
    "browser.sessionstore.resume_from_crash": "false",
    "browser.shell.checkDefaultBrowser": "false",
    "browser.tabs.warnOnClose": "false",
    "browser.tabs.warnOnOpen": "false",
    "browser.startup.page": "0",
    "browser.safebrowsing.malware.enabled": "false",
    "startup.homepage_welcome_url": "\"about:blank\"",
    "devtools.errorconsole.enabled": "true",
    "dom.disable_open_during_load": "false",
    "extensions.autoDisableScopes" : 10,
    "extensions.logging.enabled": "true",
    "extensions.update.enabled": "false",
    "extensions.update.notifyUser": "false",
    "network.manage-offline-status": "false",
    "network.http.max-connections-per-server": "10",
    "network.http.phishy-userpass-length": "255",
    "offline-apps.allow_by_default": "true",
    "prompts.tab_modal.enabled": "false",
    "security.fileuri.origin_policy": "3",
    "security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy": "false",
    "security.warn_entering_secure": "false",
    "security.warn_entering_secure.show_once": "false",
    "security.warn_entering_weak": "false",
    "security.warn_entering_weak.show_once": "false",
    "security.warn_leaving_secure": "false",
    "security.warn_leaving_secure.show_once": "false",
    "security.warn_submit_insecure": "false",
    "security.warn_viewing_mixed": "false",
    "security.warn_viewing_mixed.show_once": "false",
    "signon.rememberSignons": "false",
    "toolkit.networkmanager.disable": "true",
    "toolkit.telemetry.enabled": "false",
    "toolkit.telemetry.prompted": "2",
    "toolkit.telemetry.rejected": "true",
    "javascript.options.showInConsole": "true",
    "browser.dom.window.dump.enabled": "true",
    "webdriver_accept_untrusted_certs": "true",
    "webdriver_enable_native_events": "true",
    "webdriver_assume_untrusted_issuer": "true",
    "dom.max_script_run_time": "30",
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I dont see browser size settings in there, but it's useful to have the list and the link all the same.

Answer (score 1):

### <**Chrome**>

*`-window-size` and `window-size` also work:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--window-size=1024,768")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

*This code below also works according to [the doc](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/windows/#set-window-size):

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
```

### <**Microsoft Edge**>

*`-window-size` and `window-size` also work:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
options.add_argument("--window-size=1024,768")
driver = webdriver.Edge(options=options)
```

*This code below also works according to [the doc](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/windows/#set-window-size):

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
```

### <**Firefox**>

*-width and -height also work while `width` and `height` don't work:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("--window-size=1024,768")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```

*This code below also works according to [the doc](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/windows/#set-window-size):

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.window.width',0)
profile.set_preference('browser.window.height',0)
profile.update_preferences()
```

write this code into setup part of  your test code, before the: `webdriver.Firefox()` line.

Comment: The question is about setting the initial windows size using **python**.... Anyway, this doesn't work either using python, at least using selenium 2.46.0 and Firefox 38.0.5

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below code to set the resolution on mac chrome and windows chrome.

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1280, 768));
```

Use the below code to test the resolution changes:-

```
Dimension dimension = driver.manage().window().getSize();
LOGGER.info("dimension is " + dimension);
```