# How to set window size for Chrome in Selenium?

Tags: google-chrome, testing, browser, selenium-chromedriver, window-size

I'm using Selenium WebDriver for automation and I'm using **Chromedriver**.

I have noticed that when my driver runs and opens the chrome browser, it opens the browser with a strange size.
I tried to fixed it but in vain.

Does anybody know how can I change it?

Comment: What language binding are you using? The API provides methods to set windows size regardless which driver you are using (unless you have specific issues with ChromeDriver, then please provide more information in that case). Here's an article you might want to have a look. [How to get window size, resize or maximize window using Selenium WebDriver](http://yizeng.me/2014/02/23/how-to-get-window-size-resize-or-maximize-window-using-selenium-webdriver/)

Answer (score 125):

## Python

#### Drivers

```
chrome = 57.0.2987.133
chromedriver = 2.27.440174
```

#### Code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
driver = Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: Yes, latest window resize is buggy in chromedriver, they say its fixed in 2.28 version , but I got error in that version also . I also end up using command line switches and passing window size as args.

Comment: Thanks! Using ChromeDriver 2.32 and this is the only option that works for a headless variation. C# Windows. driver.Manage().Window.Size does not work.

Comment: I notice that it seems to have a maximum size that it silently reverts to if you go over. (My machine, 1940 pixels high, but it seems to differ.)

Comment: Update: My comment is true for Chrome, but not Firefox.

Comment: this notation also works `chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=768x1024')`

Comment: @Levon that format didn't work for me using Selenium .NET, while the format in the answer did work

Comment: chrome_options is now deprecated in favour of "options", so it should be `driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)`

Answer (score 37):

Use this for your custom size:

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1024,768));
```

you can change your dimensions as per your requirements.

Comment: Doesn't seems to work for headless Chrome (version 60). However, @Yonatan Kiron's answer does works

Comment: @MiguelD'Alessio Glad that it helped :)

Comment: Puppeteer solution: see [my answer on another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64868797/539149) to do it in  using `session.send('Browser.setWindowBounds', {windowId, bounds: {width: width, height: height}})` in a Chrome Devtools Protocol (CDP) session.

Answer (score 18):

```
#use chrome webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('path to /chromedriver')
driver.set_window_size(1400,1000)
```

Comment: this is link to webdriver chrome http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.22/

Comment: this one worked for me. Driver Version 81.0.4044.138

Comment: Also a Winner. Thanks dude

Answer (score 12):

C# version of @yonatan-kiron's answer, and Selenium's `using` statement from their example code.

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--window-size=1300,1000");

using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: All the other answers but this are non-default window size, meaning it will still launch ugly +1.

Answer (score 10):

try this

```
using System.Drawing;
driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(width, height);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try with `driver.manage.window.maximize();` to maximize window.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want a full screen, but to fix the window's size by my own size.
The Chromedriver for some reason fix the window size when open the browser.

Answer (score 4):

RUBY

---

**Approach #1**

```
options = {
      'chromeOptions' => {
          'args' => ['start-fullscreen']
      }
  }

caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(options)
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, desired_capabilities: caps
```

**Approach #2**

```
options = {
      'chromeOptions' => {
          'args' => ['window-size=640,480']
      }
  }

caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(options)
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, desired_capabilities: caps
```

**Approach #3**

```
max_width, max_height = @driver.execute_script("return [window.screen.availWidth, window.screen.availHeight];")
@driver.manage.window.resize_to(max_width, max_height)
```

**Approach #4**

```
@driver.manage.window.maximize
```

**Approach #5**

```
target_size = Selenium::WebDriver::Dimension.new(1600, 1268)
@driver.manage.window.size = target_size
```

**Approach #6**

```
@driver.manage.window.resize_to(640, 480)
```

**Approach #7**

```
@driver.execute_script("window.resizeTo(640, 480);")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the Facebook language binding for php try this:

```
$driver->manage()->window()->setSize(new WebDriverDimension(1024,768));
```

Answer (score 2):

In java/groovy try:

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;         
import org.openqa.selenium.Point;

...

java.awt.Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

Dimension maximizedScreenSize = new Dimension((int) screenSize.getWidth(), (int) screenSize.getHeight());
driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(0, 0));
driver.manage().window().setSize(maximizedScreenSize);
```

this will open browser in fullscreen

Answer (score 2):

Following chrome options worked for me for headless chrome:

**IN JAVA:**

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
chromeOptions.setHeadless(true);
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
driver.get("your-site");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

selenium-java: 3.8.1

chromedriver: 2.43

Chrome: v69-71

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Clojure and https://github.com/semperos/clj-webdriver you can use this snippet to resize the browser.

```
(require '[clj-webdriver.taxi :as taxi])

; Open browser
(taxi/set-driver! {:browser :chrome} "about:blank")

; Resize browser
(-> taxi/*driver* (.webdriver) (.manage) (.window) 
  (.setSize (org.openqa.selenium.Dimension. 0 0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Dimension Class` for controlling window size.

```
Dimension d = new Dimension(1200,800);  //(x,y coordinators in pixels) 
driver.manage().window().setSize(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby version:

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome("chromeOptions" => {"args"=> ["--window-size=1280,960"]})

url = "http://localhost:9515"  # if you are using local chrome or url = Browserstack/ saucelabs hub url if you are using cloud service providers.

 Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, :url => url, :desired_capabilities => caps)
```

resize chrome is buggy in latest chromedrivers , it fails intermittanly with this failure message.

```
                        unknown error: cannot get automation extension
from timeout: cannot determine loading status
from timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -65.294
  (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.76)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455517 (2c6d2707d8ea850c862f04ac066724273981e88f)
```

And resizeTo via javascript also not supported for chrome started via selenium webdriver. So the last option was using command line switches.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the total screen resolution you are using is larger than the window size you want to use you can use this (C#):

```
browserDriver.Manage().Window.Size = windowSize;
```

If your screen resolution is smaller then you are out of luck. I tried different ways such as:

```
chromeOptions.AddArgument($"window-size={windowSize.Width},{windowSize.Height}");
```

Or even importing the move window function to resize a window:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int Width, int Height, bool Repaint);

// Example
MoveWindow(process.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, windowSize.Width, windowSize.Height, true);
```

But none of these work. It seems that chrome does something different to prevent the window size from growing bigger than the screen resolution. With Firefox I didn't see this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience setting size from the webdriver is not always reliable.
It might apply it to the viewport only or might fall into other issues (like minimum screen size for that particular webdriver).

See https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#dfn-set-window-rect

> The specification does not guarantee that the resulting window size will exactly match that which was requested. In particular the implementation is expected to clamp values that are larger than the physical screen dimensions, or smaller than the minimum window size.

I'm going to try with setting capabilites to see if it's any better.

Answer (score 0):

The screen resolution of my device was lower than the screen resolution expected by the test.

Workaround that worked for me:

```
options.EnableMobileEmulation(new ChromiumMobileEmulationDeviceSettings
{
   Height = 1080,
   Width = 1920,
   EnableTouchEvents = false,
   UserAgent = "Responsive"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can set window size for Chrome with Selenium as shown below. *`-window-size` and `window-size` also work:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--window-size=1024,768")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

And in Python, you can also do it with the code below according to [the doc](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/windows/#set-window-size):

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
```

*[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397483/how-to-set-browsers-width-and-height-in-selenium-webdriver/77085800#77085800) explains it more.

Answer (score 0):

update 12/2023

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--app=http:// abc. com ");

//options.AddArgument("--window-size=400,500"); //if this config does not work, try Window size bellow

ChromeDriver webBrowser = new ChromeDriver(options);

webBrowser.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(400,500);