# Puppeteer always loads mobile script on remote server

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, web-crawler, puppeteer, chromium

I'm trying to scrape (headless) this [URL's](https://www.usatoday.com/obituaries) scripts but I notice that whenever I'm doing it on my local machine I'm getting: `"https://vidstat.taboola.com/lite-unit/4.1.0/UnitFeedManagerDesktop.min.js"` script.

The issue is when I'm calling the API for scraping on a remote server (postman) I'm always getting a script that should appear only on mobile devices only:
`https://vidstat.taboola.com/lite-unit/4.1.0/UnitFeedManagerMobile.min.js"`

this is my code:

```js
public async fetchScripts(url: string, waitFor = 'cdn-pipes.js') {
    
    const page = await this.browser.newPage();

    try {
      await page.goto(url, {timeout: 10000, waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});
      const func = waitFor ? `document.documentElement.innerHTML.indexOf("${waitFor}") !== -1 || document.documentElement.innerHTML.indexOf("spa-detector") !== -1` :
        'document.readyState === "complete"';
      await page.waitForFunction(func, {polling: 500, timeout: 8000}).catch(reason => {
        console.error('page.waitForFunction', {error: reason, url});
      });

      const pageUrls = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const urlArray = Array.from(document.scripts).map((link) => link.src).filter(value => value.includes('taboola.com'));

        return [...new Set(urlArray)];
      });

      console.log('fetchMinimal - urlsArray ', {pageUrls});

      return pageUrls;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('fetchMinimal - error ', e);
    } finally {
      await page.close();
    }

  }
```

I'm suspecting this is a CDN issue that saving old scripts somehow IDK, any thoughts?

UPDATE:

It's happening because the page loads the mobile script only if
`window.matchMedia(" only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px)").matches` which is always true on chromium-browser.

Comment: In your case, the CDN is probably serving the UnitFeedManagerMobile.min.js script to your remote server because it thinks that the server is a mobile device. You can confirm this by checking the user agent of your remote server. You can try to spoof the user agent of your remote server to make it look like a desktop computer. This will tell the CDN to serve the UnitFeedManagerDesktop.min.js script.

Comment: this is the remote user agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/99.0.4844.84 Safari/537.36' I set my local user agent to this and it didn't change much

Comment: Set the user agent of your remote server to something other than Chromium-based. You can do this by setting the user-agent header in your request. Also, you can use a different headless browser. There are other headless browsers available, such as PhantomJS and SlimerJS. These browsers may not have the same issue as Chromium-based browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52553311/how-to-set-max-viewport-in-puppeteer) - I managed to solve it by providing `args: ['--window-size=1920,1080']` to `puppeteer.launch`