# Scraping Cart items for price in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape cart items and get their respective price of a shopping website.

So far this is my code but getting an error. I think I am not getting the proper XPath

```
from  selenium import webdriver
chrome_path =r"C:\Users\aq4'july\Desktop\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.myntra.com/")

#User Login
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="desktop-header-cnt"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/a[2]""")
```

The error I am getting is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="desktop-header-cnt"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/a[2]""").click()
  File "C:\Users\aq4'july\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\aq4'july\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 501, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\aq4'july\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 311, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\aq4'july\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 237, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.84)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)
```

Please feel free to Use username and Password (sarwarhayatt@outlook.com, sunset@paris  ) respectively for test purpose.

Note: I am using python 3.6 and please highlight I missed anything while asking the question.

Comment: The expression looks good and should match the element. What error are you getting? Have you tried waiting with an [Explicit Wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)?

Comment: No..Can you please try extending this code also further I don't know how to list cart items

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful informations.

Comment: I don't see cart items on page `https://www.myntra.com` but only on `https://www.myntra.com/checkout/cart`. Maybe create minimal working example which we could run.

Comment: @furas Done.Added couple of items to cart.

Comment: error shows `"Message: element not visible"` because `Selenium` can't click element if it is not displayed on screen. You have to `click()` icon which shows menu.

Comment: or load directly `https://www.myntra.com/checkout/cart` using `driver.get()` to get pages with items in cart.

Comment: BTW: your xpath tries to click `"PhonePe"` or `"Cashback"` in menu

Comment: @furas that's cool ........but if you are not already logged in nothing will show in the cart. So we have to log in first and logging option come with a hovering button.

Comment: I thought you already logged in so you need only get page with cart. After you logged in you can use `https://www.myntra.com/checkout/cart` directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you logged in you can go to cart directly

```
driver.get('https://www.myntra.com/checkout/cart')
```

or you can click "bag" button

```
item = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.desktop-cart')
item.click()
```

Full code tested with `Firefox()`

**EDIT:** sometimes it has problem to login but it seems `sleep()` resolves this problem.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

LOGIN = 'xxx@xxx.com' 
PASSWORD = 'PaSwOrD'

# --- start ---

chrome_path =r"C:\Users\aq4'july\Desktop\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

#driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# resize window so all elements are visible 
# and the is no problem to click them 
driver.maximize_window()
#driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
#driver.execute_script("window.resizeTo(1920,1080)") # doesn't work for me

# --- main page ---

#driver.get("https://www.myntra.com/")

# --- login ---

driver.get('https://www.myntra.com/login?referer=https://www.myntra.com/')

time.sleep(1)

item = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.login-user-input-email')
item.send_keys(LOGIN)

item = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.login-user-input-password')
item.send_keys(PASSWORD)

item = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.login-login-button')
item.click()

time.sleep(1)

# --- main page ---

#driver.get("https://www.myntra.com/")

# --- cart ---

item = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.desktop-cart')
item.click()

# or

#driver.get('https://www.myntra.com/checkout/cart')
```

Resizing: [How do I resize the window in Chrome and Firefox when testing with Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29600093/how-do-i-resize-the-window-in-chrome-and-firefox-when-testing-with-selenium)

Scrolling: [How can I scroll a web page using selenium webdriver in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986631/how-can-i-scroll-a-web-page-using-selenium-webdriver-in-python)

Comment: just wanna ask you..Does same code can run on the chrome too. If we change  `driver = webdriver.Chrome`

Comment: it should work on Chrome too - I don't have driver for Chrome in Selenium.

Comment: I installed new Chrome driver and it works (on Linux Mint) but on my computer it opens Chrome with narrow window so `bag` icon is invisible so `click` doesn't work. Code should scroll window or resize window.  But using `driver.get()` I can get page with cart

Comment: can you add that code which resizes window in your answer?

Comment: Now I'm searching solution for resizing :)

Answer (score 1):

Bro if you want to login just go to login page 
and do stuff....
do count double quotes" and escape sequences

```
from  selenium import webdriver
import time
chrome_path ="chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.myntra.com/login")

time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"mountRoot\"]/div/div/div/form/fieldset[1]/div[1]/input").send_keys("sarwarhayatt@outlook.com")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"mountRoot\"]/div/div/div/form/fieldset[1]/div[2]/input").send_keys("sunset@paris")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"mountRoot\"]/div/div/div/form/fieldset[2]/button").click()

time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"desktop-header-cnt\"]/div[2]/div[2]/a").click()
time.sleep(2)
print (driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"prod-item-1514127198\"]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div").text)

time.sleep(10)
driver.quit()
```

your error is right here:
3 double quotes and  "desktop-header-cnt" double quotes here is breaking the complete string 
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="desktop-header-cnt"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/a[2]""")

Comment: Very Well @zxcV32 Thank you