# Python selenium. How to get text of chrome mode mobile

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

Sorry i' want to get element of mobile chrome.
Now i can get in body.but can't get class in body "tableID1"
How to get element and text of "tableID1 - tableID10"

[image: a busy cat]

my code can get only body but can't get another element.

`driver.find_element_by_id("body").get_attribute('innerHTML')`

Answer (score 0):

Jsut need to change the window size to show the id you want to see.

For Chromejust add before "webdriver.Chrome" init:

`chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")`

**For all browsers:**

There is an official selenium python binding for that: http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.set_window_size

`driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)`

or

`driver.maximize_window()`

or with javascript

`driver.execute_script("window.resizeTo(1920,1080)")`

Source : [How do I resize the window in Chrome and Firefox when testing with Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29600093/how-do-i-resize-the-window-in-chrome-and-firefox-when-testing-with-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

Induce `WebDriverWait` and `presence_of_all_elements_located`() or `visibility_of_all_elements_located`() and use the below `xpath`. 
Try `ele.text` or `ele.get_attribute('textContent')`

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

elements=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='table_road_set'][starts-with(@id,'tableID')]")))
for ele in elements:
    print(ele.text)
    print(ele.get_attribute('textContent'))
```

OR

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

elements=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='table_road_set'][starts-with(@id,'tableID')]")))
for ele in elements:
    print(ele.text)
    print(ele.get_attribute('textContent'))
```

---

You can use following Css Selector as well.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

elements=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.table_road_set[id^='tableID']")))
for ele in elements:
    print(ele.text)
    print(ele.get_attribute('textContent'))
```

Comment: elements=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.table_road_set[id^='tableID']")))
  File "H:\Python\WPy64-3680\python-3.6.8.amd64\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: I believe element is not visible on the page.try presence_of_all_elements_located()