# How to set browser viewport size

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, browser, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to create a cross-browser `Python-Selenium` test script. So I need all results to be same no matter which `webdriver` (`Chrome` or `IE`) I use.
I can set browser window size as follow:

```
driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
```

But following code will return different values for `Chrome` and `IE`:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('some_xpath')
element.location
```

as viewport area (where web-content displayed) sizes are different (`Chrome`- 1910x998, `IE`- 1904x965) despite of same window size. To get these values I used

```
driver.execute_script('return document.documentElement.clientHeight')
driver.execute_script('return document.documentElement.clientWidth')
```

so I tried

```
driver.execute_script('document.documentElement.clientHeight = "990px";')
driver.execute_script('document.documentElement.clientWeight = "1900px";')
```

but with no luck

So the question is how to set browser viewport size in `selenium`?

Comment: have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397483/how-do-i-set-browser-width-and-height-in-selenium-webdriver it's a java example but there is a python equivalent code

Comment: @Pete, What you mean??? I've already made it :)

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida, thanks for a suggestion, but it seem to be a different issue

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here is function to set the viewport size:

```
def set_viewport_size(driver, width, height):
    window_size = driver.execute_script("""
        return [window.outerWidth - window.innerWidth + arguments[0],
          window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight + arguments[1]];
        """, width, height)
    driver.set_window_size(*window_size)
```

Usage :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# set the viewport size to 800 x 600
set_viewport_size(driver, 800, 600)

# display the viewport size
print driver.execute_script("return [window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight];")
```

Comment: this will also include size of horizontal and vertical page scroll bars (about 17px each), but its ok :) thanks

Comment: To get the viewport size without the scrollbars size, use `document.body.clientWidth` and `document.body.clientHeight` instead of `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the **Java** version for @Florent B. answer :

```
        int width = "500";
        int height = "500";

        //Remove the window from fullscreen (optional), if it s in fullscreen the outerHeight is not accurate
        browser.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(800,800));

        JavascriptExecutor js= (JavascriptExecutor)browser;

        String windowSize = js.executeScript("return (window.outerWidth - window.innerWidth + "+width+") + ',' + (window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight + "+height+"); ").toString();

        //Get the values
        width = Integer.parseInt(windowSize.split(",")[0]);
        height = Integer.parseInt(windowSize.split(",")[1]);

        //Set the window
        browser.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(width, height));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the **C# Version** for @Florent B. answer:

```
   public static void SetViewportSize(RemoteWebDriver driver, int width, int height)
{            
    var jsGetPadding = @"return [ window.outerWidth - window.innerWidth,window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight ];";
    var paddingArray = driver.ExecuteScript(jsGetPadding) as ReadOnlyCollection<object>; 
    driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(width + int.Parse(paddingArray[0].ToString()), height + int.Parse(paddingArray[1].ToString()));

}
```

Usage:

```
  RemoteWebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
  SetViewportSize(driver,800, 800);
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm using this:

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(new org.openqa.selenium.Dimension(1900, 990));
```

Where 1900 is the width, and 990 is the height.

Comment: From the docs: "[...] This will change the outer window dimension, not just the view port [...]"