# How to send info to site about desktop resolution in Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am developing an application and I need to send some info about the resolution of a browser's window and the resolution of a monitor.

The resolution is currently set to: 1920x1080.  I want to send 800x600 as the resolution of the desktop.

Here's an example:

The desktop resolution is 800x600 and I set the chrome browser resolution to 480x320.  I do this with the following snippet of code:

```
driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(480, 320);
```

How I can do this with Selenium? How can I properly send this info?

Comment: I tried to reword your question, can you first see if it makes sense.  If not I can rollback my edits.  Also, can you see if this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397483/how-do-i-set-browser-width-and-height-in-selenium-webdriver

Comment: Thanks. Everything is right. I found decision of my problem, but it for Firefox: https://www.browserstack.com/automate/c-sharp

Comment: If you found an answer to your question, please post it as an answer and accept it. Thanks.

Comment: I found a decision using other browser. I work with Chrome, but found for FF.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty straightforward now with Chrome.  Just do the following:

```
ChromeOptions displayOptions = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
driver = new ChromeDriver(displayOptions);  
//  Initialize your driver object here.
IWebDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver("path to driver here", displayOptions);
```

This will initialize the `driver object` to be full-screen when it is instantiated.