# How to set window position of Firefox browser through Selenium using FirefoxProfile or FirefoxOptions

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I need to change the position of the Firefox window by creating the driver with:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

I know it's possible to change the window position after the driver was created:

```
driver.set_window_position()
```

I can't find out how to do it using Firefox profile or options:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("some_preference", my_preference)
```

or

```
options = Options()
options.some_optins = my_options
```

and finally:

```
driver = Webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, options=options)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You saw it right.

### set_window_position()

[`set_window_position()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.set_window_position) sets the `x`,`y` position of the current window.

- Implementation:

  ```
    set_window_position(x, y, windowHandle='current')
    Sets the x,y position of the current window. (window.moveTo)

    Arguments :
        x: the x-coordinate in pixels to set the window position
        y: the y-coordinate in pixels to set the window position
    Usage :
        driver.set_window_position(0,0)
  ```
- Definition:

  ```
    def set_window_position(self, x, y, windowHandle='current'):
        if self.w3c:
            if windowHandle != 'current':
            warnings.warn("Only 'current' window is supported for W3C compatibile browsers.")
            return self.set_window_rect(x=int(x), y=int(y))
        else:
            self.execute(Command.SET_WINDOW_POSITION,
                 {
                     'x': int(x),
                     'y': int(y),
                     'windowHandle': windowHandle
                 })
  ```

So to summarize, `window_position` is coupled to the *window handle* pertaining to the browser and can be handled by *webdriver* instance only.

This functionality can't be handled either through:

- `firefox_profile` -> [`set_preference(key, value)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_firefox/selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile.html#selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile.FirefoxProfile.set_preference): Sets the preference that we want in the profile.
- `firefox.options` -> [`set_preference(name, value)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_firefox/selenium.webdriver.firefox.options.html#selenium.webdriver.firefox.options.Options.set_preference): Sets a preference.

Comment: According to this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37151037/8973620) you can do it in Chrome. It should be possible in Firefox as well.

Comment: And to boot `driver.set_window_position(0,0)` actually positions the window about 10 pixels in from the left , so it's not even working correctly. (Windows10)
A value of -5 for the x coord worked for me, it seems someone added the system metrics SM_CXBORDER furniture value twice?