# Trying to Webscrape on site that requires log in but is Dynamically loaded, Python, Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape my school's website for my upcoming assignments, and add it to a file. However I need to log in to find my assessments, and the website is dynamically loaded, so I need to use Selenium.
My problem is I'm using the requests package to authenticate myself on the website, but I don't know how to open the website with Selenium. Then I'm hoping to take the HTML and scrape it with Beautiful Soup, I would prefer not to learn another Framework.
Here is my Code:
'''
import json
from requests import Session
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

```
# Login function that takes the username and password
def login(username, password):
    s = Session()
    payload = {
        'username' : username,
        'password': password
    }
    res = s.post('https://www.website_url.com', json=payload)
    print(res.content)
    return s

session = login('username', "password")
driver_path = r'C:\Users\username\Downloads\edgedriver_win64\msedgedriver.exe'
url = 'https://www.website_url.com/assessments/upcoming'
driver = webdriver.Edge(driver_path)
driver.get(url)
```

'''
The website loads up, but it reverts me to the login page.
P.S. I managed to open the website with Beautiful Soup, but since it is dynamically loaded I can't scrape it.

Edit:
Hey, thanks for the answer! I tried it and it should work, sadly, it is throwing a lot of errors:

```
[9308:26392:0215/111025.239:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(251)] START: GetDefaultBrowser(). If you don't see the END: message, this is crbug.com/1216328.        
[9308:7708:0215/111025.270:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [11:10:25.271] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[9308:7708:0215/111025.281:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [11:10:25.287] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
ode connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[9308:26392:0215/111025.313:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(255)] END: GetDefaultBrowser()
```

I'm not sure what this is, I had a look at the Xpath and it seems to have changed when I resized it I think.
My teacher told me (he isn't familiar with python) that I should try login to the website on a window and open another tab with Selenium so I could avoid the login because I'm logged in on the other tab, I've looked around of how to open a new tab not a window but I can't find anything.
Thank you!

Hey, I just found the answer, the problem was the HTML id, and Xpath was changing each reloads and I didn't realize I could use CSS selectors, so i did that, you've helped me a lot I appreciate it.

```
login_box = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div.login > div.auth > div.loginBox')
input_boxes = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.login>.auth label>input')
input_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.login>.auth button')
input_boxes[0].send_keys(username)
input_boxes[1].send_keys(password)
input_buttons[0].click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use selenium webdriver to login to your school's website to have the session in webdriver and then load the page you want to scrape.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver_path = r'C:\Users\username\Downloads\edgedriver_win64\msedgedriver.exe'
url = 'https://www.website_url.com/assessments/upcoming'
login_url = 'https://www.website_url.com'

driver = webdriver.Edge(driver_path)
driver.get(login_url)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("username input xpath").sendkeys(username)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("password input xpath").sendkeys(password)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("submit button xpath").click()

# wait for the page to load
driver.get(url)
```

You can also directly POST the credentials to the login page:

```
webdriver.request('POST', login_url, data={"username": username, "password": password})
```

- For the window size part, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61715929/is-there-anyway-to-define-windows-size-for-edge-browser-with-selenium) should help.
- You can ignore these errors, it's just selenium/webdriver log.
- I personally don't think you need a new tab but you can try it out. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431765/open-web-in-new-tab-selenium-python) post has lot of helpfull answers.

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Hey I edited my post btw, I don't know how to add another question to this thing @ZhorGen

Comment: I edited mine too :)

Comment: Hey, thanks so much!!! I had to make a couple of work arounds but it works! You really helped me thankyou!!! I'll edit my post to show the answer

Comment: You're welcome it was my pleasure