# How to take screenshot with the same window size in Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, screenshot, window-size

I want to take a screenshot in headless mode using [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/) at specific resolution, but even if I set the driver window size, the screenshot is taken at a different resolution:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

width = 1024
height = 768

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.set_window_size(width, height)

driver.get('https://google.com')
print('Window size', driver.get_window_size())
# Window size {'width': 1024, 'height': 768}

driver.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')  # <--  Screenshot is saved at different resolution
```

How can I take a screenshot at the same resolution of driver window size (1024x768 in this example) without have to post-process the saved image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the `window-size` option you could add.

```
chrome_options.add_argument('window-size=1024x768')
```

Comment: After writing this answer I gave your script a try and it worked as expected. I checked the image properties and the screenshot was indeed saved at resolution 1024 x 768.

Comment: Thanks, `add_argument('window-size=1024x768')` did the trick

Answer (score 0):

With the code below, you can set window size. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397483/how-to-set-browsers-width-and-height-in-selenium-webdriver/77085800#77085800) explains it more:

```py
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1024,768')
```

Or:

```py
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
```