# Upgrade to Selenium 4 - The type or namespace name 'ChromeMobileEmulationDeviceSettings' could not be found

Tags: selenium

I'm upgrading a C# program that was using Selenium 3.  After updating Selenium to version 4, I get this error

> The type or namespace name 'ChromeMobileEmulationDeviceSettings' could not be found

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
...
var chromeMobileEmulationDeviceSettings = new ChromeMobileEmulationDeviceSettings(userAgentString)
{
    Width = width,
    Height = height
};

var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.EnableMobileEmulation(chromeMobileEmulationDeviceSettings);
chromeOptions.AddArguments("headless");

_webDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);

_webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

I don't see any mention in the docs, etc., of that class being deprecated.
I want to force the 'browser' to have a very specific height/width when it is opened.
I've seen related answers here
[How do I set browser width and height in Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397483/how-do-i-set-browser-width-and-height-in-selenium-webdriver)
But I have a similar concern about setting the size before instantiating the driver, and also those answers are 'old', so what is best practice for doing this in Selenium 4?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `ChromeMobileEmulationDeviceSettings` with `ChromiumMobileEmulationDeviceSettings`. The name just updated.