# How to use selenium.webdriver.firefox.options?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver, geckodriver

The goal is to automate the web browser to start with a specific window size.

I've tried two implementations. Implementation with `chromedriver` does the job, while the implementation with `geckodriver` fails. To be precise, both implementations start the browser, but only one of them sets the specified window size.
I would like to understand why. Am I using it wrong or something else is at hand?

Implementation no. 1, with `geckodriver` fails to set the window size:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service

geckodriver_path = Service('/usr/bin/geckodriver')

firefox_options = Options()
firefox_options.add_argument('--window-size=800,800')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service = geckodriver_path, options = firefox_options)

driver.get("http://www.wikipedia.org")
print(driver.get_window_size())
```

Implementation no. 2, with `chromedriver` sets the window size correctly:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

chromedriver_path = Service('/usr/bin/chromedriver')

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=800,800')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = chromedriver_path, options = chrome_options)

driver.get("http://www.wikipedia.org")
print(driver.get_window_size())
```

Additional info:

```
[boris@E7490-DELL ~]$ python -V
Python 3.10.5
[boris@E7490-DELL ~]$ chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 103.0.5060.53 (a1711811edd74ff1cf2150f36ffa3b0dae40b17f-refs/branch-heads/5060@{#853})
[boris@E7490-DELL ~]$ geckodriver -V
geckodriver 0.31.0 (b617178ef491 2022-04-06 11:57 +0000)
[boris@E7490-DELL ~]$ google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 103.0.5060.53 
[boris@E7490-DELL ~]$ firefox -v
Mozilla Firefox 101.0.1

[boris@E7490-DELL ~]$ python
Python 3.10.5 (main, Jun  9 2022, 00:00:00) [GCC 12.1.1 20220507 (Red Hat 12.1.1-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import selenium
>>> selenium.__version__
'4.1.0'
```

Comment: This looks like a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397483/how-do-i-set-browser-width-and-height-in-selenium-webdriver

Comment: Thanks @dosas, I haven't seen this one before, but I did find an answer in there

Answer (score 0):

Firefox requires separation of the with and height dimensions.

```
firefox_options.add_argument('--width=800')
firefox_options.add_argument('--height=800')
```